# PHP - prevent .aspx from downloading

Tags: php

ok, dont know if it is even possible.. this is how it looks like right now

index.php

```
<iframe id="graph" name="mainFrame" src="https://login.ntm.eu/paperlogin.aspx?referrer=http://www.nsd.se/inc/sso.aspx&callback=jQuery1830045579810107531614_1393544826347&username=username&password=password&rememberme=false&_=1393544923199" frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

..how can i prevent client to get this popup box with "do you want to save paperlogin.aspx" ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `how can i prevent client to get this popup box` -- Host `paperlogin.aspx` with a proper hosting that will execute ASP pages server side **or rewrite it into a PHP page.**

Comment: @Prix thanks for reply! ok, i think i understand what you mean but i cant change that string because its a URL from GET.

when you mean rewite it into a php page im a bit confused.. do you mean like
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.webpage.com/');
echo $contents; 
?

Comment: If that site is not yours then its broken, if it is yours then it needs to be hosted on a Windows server with IIS in order for ASP to work, that is why it tells you to download it rather then being executed server side.